# How can I export a struct in IDA Pro to a c-style struct?

Tags: ida, c, ida-plugin, struct

I have a struct in IDA Pro that I want to export to a c-style struct. For example:

```
00000000 ICreateErrorInfo struc ; (sizeof=0x4, align=0x4, standard type)
00000000                                         ; XREF: sub_73C9D0r
00000000 lpVtbl          dd ?                    ; offset
00000004 ICreateErrorInfo ends
```

I want to export the above to something similar to:

```
typedef struct ICreateErrorInfo {
    int lpVtbl;
} ICreateErrorInfo;
```

I am also using HexRaysCodeXplorer if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2409).

It is possible to export a structure by going in **Local Types** (<kbd>Shift+F1</kbd>). Then select the structure you want to export and in the contextual menu choose either **Edit** or **Export to header file**. It is possible to export multiple structures by holding Shift when selecting them.

Comment: You can also export from the file menu. `File -> Produce File -> Create C header file...`.